# error while using a table valued function for base conversion

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am getting an arithmetic overflow error while running the table valued function for around 50000 records.

Error:"Arithmetic overflow error for type int, value = 2147483648.000000"

I dont have the same issue when i use a scalar function.I was wondering if I can overcome the issue

I got the code for baseconversion from http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/performing-base-conversions

Here are my inline and scalar functions. The Nums table has a bigint field called n. It has 200000 rows

```
   --- 
   --- Inline
   ---
   CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ConvertFromBase
   (@val AS VARCHAR(63))
   RETURNS TABLE
   RETURN
   (SELECT SUM(
   (CHARINDEX(
      SUBSTRING(@val, LEN(@val) - n + 1, 1),
      '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') - 1)
   *POWER(2, n-1) )  AS Value
 FROM Nums
 WHERE n <= LEN(@val));

   --- 
   --- Scalar
   ---

    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_ConvertFromBase
    (@val AS VARCHAR(63), @base AS int)
    RETURNS BIGINT
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @RESULT BIGINT 
    SELECT @result =SUM(
    (CHARINDEX(
      SUBSTRING(@val, LEN(@val) - n + 1, 1),
      '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') - 1)
   *POWER(@base, n-1))  
   FROM Nums
   WHERE n <= LEN(@val)

 RETURN @result
```

END

I converted the table valued function to return to a table variable and it seems to be working. This might perform suboptimally though. I need to do more research

```
  CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertFromBasenew]
  (@val AS VARCHAR(63), @base AS bigint)
  RETURNS @TableVar TABLE(VALUE BIGINT)
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @TableVar
  SELECT SUM(CONVERT(BIGINT,
   (CHARINDEX(
      SUBSTRING(@val, LEN(@val) - n + 1, 1),
      '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') - 1)
   *CAST(POWER(@base, n-1) AS BIGINT)))  AS Value
  FROM Nums
  WHERE n <= LEN(@val)
  RETURN
 END
```

Code I am using to call the function

```
    SELECT  * FROM dbo.FinalBitmapTable
    CROSS APPLY dbo.ConvertFromBase(fINALBitmap,2) b
```

Comment: I think you need a cast to BIGINT inside the SUM expression?

Comment: I had tried that, but, that doesnt work. It looks like it has something to do with the number of rows on the table I am applying the function to. I am not able to figure out at which point its breaking. It works fine with smaller number of records in the table

Comment: Do you have more than 2 billion rows?

Comment: No, I only have 80,000 rows at any given time

Comment: Can you show the largest value that is passed into @val (and consider "largest" in two senses: longest string and largest number - which should be the same of course, depending on how many significant digits are actually stored).

Comment: I converted the table valued function to return to a table variable and it seems to be working. This might perform suboptimally though. I need to do more research. I cant post it as an answer due to the limitations here, but, i edited my question above with the new function i created

Comment: @AaronBertrand, the biggest value I was testing with is '1111111111111111'. It always works when i call it with individual values. it just fails when have a large number of records. After analysing my data, i realised that i have fewer distinct values, so, I also optimized my final code to just get a set with bitmasks and values and joined back

Comment: you need to show us the SQL code that is calling the function(s).

Comment: @RBarryYoung, I added the call to the question above. But, its just a table with bitmap values.

Comment: The reason that it works now isn't because you changed it to a non-inline TVF, it's because you added "CONVERT(BIGINT,..)" inside the SUM function.  Try that on your original.

Comment: Oops, rather, its the CAST(.. as BIGINT) around the POWER function.  Hmm, or maybe both.  Either way, it'll still only be accurate up to 15 decimal digits and not the full 18+ of a BIGINT.

Comment: The CAST and CONVERT don't help. I was playing around with multiple versions of my function, so, this one has the CAST/CONVERT in it

Answer (score 1):

This

```
SELECT POWER(2, 31)
```

doesn't work (produces an arithmetic overflow error). But this

```
SELECT POWER(CAST(2 AS bigint), 31)
```

does:

```
----------
2147483648
```

The `@base` parameter has different type in your two functions where it is present. The issue is with the one where the parameter is `int`, and the other one, which works, as you say, has `@base` as `bigint` Seems pretty much consistent with my find, I guess.